# Proposal: Blacklist [sentences]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleaning

It seems we can achieve a consensus on a certain set of tags this time without reading too much into things. Let's clean up sentence-related tags. I just came up with a few ideas, and I present them in separate meta posts so we could discuss each of them.

**Proposal:** Blacklist [sentences](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentences)

It's a completely redundant tag and serves no purpose on the questions it's on. It's a meta tag, and meta tags have proven to be useful on ELL sometimes. This one is clearly not useful since all of the questions it's on either belong to [syntax](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax) or don't need the tag at all. I don't want it to come back. We're much better off blacklisting it.

What do you think?

Comment: I've not actually participated in tag policing on any of the Stack sites before, so I hesitate to cast a vote, but a look through the [tagged questions](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentences) does seem to indicate that this tag is simply fluff. The questions tagged solely with it can be retagged with more specific tags without trouble. Well, not trouble with choosing a new tag, anyway. Apparently you can't just edit a question and remove/add a tag - you need to make at least 6 characters worth of changes to the text as well. Lord knows why. Also, yay triangles.

Comment: No @Damien, you can make an edit that solely edits tags. It's just that if you touch the body of the post, your edit needs to be at least 6 characters long.

Comment: That's odd then, because when I go to [this question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/83574), click Edit, remove the sentences tag and add the future-tense tag, all without touching the body, I get a red box next to the post body and told "Edits must be at least 6 characters".

Comment: @Damien then I might have misunderstood the edit restrictions. Anyway, aren't there other things in that post that can be improved?

Comment: Certainly, and I plan on doing so, but in cases where the question just needs retagging, having to invent an edit in the body is a little annoying.

Comment: This restriction is only on <2k rep users. After that, you're free like a butterfly. :)

Comment: Am I then also free to [cause hurricanes in Texas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_effect)? :P

Comment: Sure. Don't tell anyone who caused that big tornado in Jupiter.

Comment: The tag has been destroyed - if it pops up again now that we're out of beta and it takes more reputation to make a new tag, we will blacklist it.

Comment: @Colleen <espresso>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The tag has been destroyed - if it pops up again now that we're out of beta and it takes more reputation to make a new tag, we will blacklist it.**

This proposal has been up-voted enough that I think there is community support for blacklisting [sentences](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentences). However, there is some interest in a related discussion: [When should the "sentences" tag be used?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/485/) that indicates some folks might be interested in saving the tag with a proper description of when it should be used.

Because this discussion has no answers and just up-votes, and the related discussion is pretty old, I think that we should take another look at the proposal and how the tag has been used in the meantime. Leave an answer or comment if you want to make a case for keeping the tag (or for some action other than blacklisting).

Comment: I would probably have advocated a system that chose a set of tags such as [sentences], [verbs], [letters] etc. to represent the grammatical unit in question, but I don't, for three reasons: (1) The name "sentences" is ambiguous and allows for a lot of confusion. When a learner asks "*find* vs. *to find*", they think they're comparing sentences, so why not add the [sentences] tag? And we can't enforce good use of a tag, since that has worked so well before. (2) A sentence may contain one clause or more, and what the question would really about is the clause, not the sentence as a whole.

Comment: (3) Going about and editing all the erroneous cases with the tag is cumbersome. Sometimes a tag is considered useful, but its misuse/abuse would make it impractical to use. [sentences], right now, is such a tag.

Comment: @Rubisco You're preaching to the choir :) I would like to get rid of it because it is often misused and I don't think a wiki will fix it, but it's been a while since we've discussed it. so I want to do a quick double check before acting.