# Impose a sentence on [sentence] (again)

Tags: discussion, tags

<sub>(if you're wondering about the pun in the title, that's a [Stack Exchange meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/257542/295232) for tag-related Meta questions)</sub>

The [sentence](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentence) tag currently has 17 questions and no tag excerpt or wiki. IMHO it's a very broad and ambiguous tag; I guess more than half of the questions here involve sentences in some way or another. If the sentence aspect is really important to the question, a more specific tag can be used, e.g. [sentence-construction](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentence-construction), [sentence-meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentence-meaning) and [sentence-structure](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentence-structure).

I propose to get rid of it, and since [something similar happened to the [sentences] tag](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3276/18673) it's probably a good idea to blacklist it (it seems that didn't happen back then, possibly because it involves a request to the Community Managers, ♦ moderators can blacklist tags themselves).

Comment: I feel like I have nuked that tag before (but not black-listed it). I assumed it was a typo due to starting to type one of the hyphenated tags, but not finishing it, but 17 questions seems like it's starting to be more than that.

Comment: I've edited out the tag since there were only 17 instances, and the tag didn't really help group those questions properly. IMO, if a tag doesn't help you get relevant "related" questions in the sidebar, it needs to be scrutinized.

Comment: I have just found out that [tag:sentence-construction] and [tag:sentence-structure] have merged. I don't think they are quite the same kind of question and I vaguely remember being able to tag questions under [tag:sentence-structure]. The merge seems to be a recent thing, but I can't find a relevant discussion here on Meta.

Comment: I’m still removing [tag:sentence] instances…